# Why is my model not binding using a post with JSON in .Net Core?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass JSON data to an action method in a .Net Core 3.1 web application.

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("JsonTest", Name="json.test")]
public ViewResult AjaxTest([FromBody] Student student)
{
  return View(student);
}
```

Model Class:

```
public class Student
{
  public Student()
  {

  }

  public Student(int studentId, string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    this.StudentId = studentId;
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;
  }

  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't matter how I hit the action method, using a web page or Postman, the Student object is not populated with the JSON from this request.

The default constructor of the Student class is called, but the properties are never set.

[image]

The result:

[image]

What is causing the object properties to not be bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json format has a wrong structure so that model binding does not work, it should be just something like this:

```
{ "StudentId" : "1", "FirstName" : "Test", "Lastname" : "Student" }
```

If you want to keep your JSON format, you need to define a view model class to map with that format like this:

```
public class StudentViewModel {
    public Student Model {get;set;}
}
```

And use it in your controller action:

```
public ViewResult AjaxTest([FromBody] StudentViewModel student){
    //...
}
```

The view model class above requires case-insensitive properties mapping, so you either need to use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to configure the json property name (`model` but not `Model`) or configure it globally via `JsonSerializerOptions` (for `System.Text.Json`) as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing).

Comment: If I change the JSON as you suggested, the student parameter comes in as null.  I've played-around with the casing of the JSON properties as well, but the Student is always null in the action method.

Comment: I got it to work.  The remaining issue is that the StudentId in the JSON needed to be in integer, not a string.  Thanks